# Dynamically create list of buttons and pass data in it?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am new to C# and I Self-teach myself C#. I am trying to create my first win8 store app in C# XAML.
The app will be for my use only and won't be published to the store.
The app web scrapes a site, and it collects some links from it and their descriptions and fills the list.
The list has link and description and looks like this:
link:  [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
description: google

link: [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com)
description: yahoo

My first problem is that i don't understand how to pass this data to the XAML page.
And my other problem is how do i create a dynamic list of buttons so if my list has 10 element i want 10 buttons on XAML page. If my list has 5 elements i want 5 buttons on XAML page.
And each button must have it's Content set to description from my list.
When i click on a button i want to pass the link that belongs to description and open another XAML page where i can use the link and do something with it.

My MainPage.xaml.cs looks lik this:

```
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyApp.HtmlParser.LinkItem> LinkItems { get; set; } 

    public MainPage()
    {
     
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlParser pars = new HtmlParser();
        pars.Uri = "http://some website.something/";
        //LinksItems = await pars.Parse();
        ObservableCollection<MyApp.HtmlParser.LinkItem> LinksItem = await pars.Parse();
        ListLinks.DataContext = LinkItems;
    }
}
```

}

My HtmlParser Class looks like this:

```
{
class HtmlParser
{

    private string sUri;

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return this.sUri; }
        set { this.sUri = value; }
    }

    public class LinkItem
    {
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }

        public LinkItem(string Link, string Description)
{
    this.link = Link;
    this.description = Description;

}

    }
   
    public HtmlParser()
    {
        this.sUri = string.Empty;
    }
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<LinkItem>> Parse()

    {
        ObservableCollection<LinkItem> listDesc = new ObservableCollection<LinkItem>();
        // Initialize http client.
         HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, this.sUri);
        message.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message);
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");

        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(result);

        //pars web page
        //var options = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("option").Skip(1)
        //    .Select(n => new
        //    {
        //        Value = n.Attributes["value"].Value,
        //        Text = n.InnerText
        //    })
        //    .ToList();

        //pars mobile web page
        var options = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Skip(1)
         .Select(n => new
         {
             Value = n.Attributes["href"].Value,
             Text = n.InnerText,

         })
         .ToList();

        foreach (var e in options)
        {
            // Add results to list:
            listDesc.Add(new LinkItem( "http://mobile.blitz-cinestar.hr/" + e.Value, e.Text));
        }
        return listDesc;
    }

}
```

}

My XAML looks like this

```
<Page
x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<ListView x:Name="ListLinks" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="495" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="382">
</ListView>
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably renamed `MyList` to `LinkItem`, which holds a link and its description;

1. Add a property of type `ObservableCollection<LinkItem>` and populate it (in this example, ill name it `MyLinks`)
2. Add a `ListView` to your MainPage.xaml
3. Set the list view's `ItemsSource` property to `{Binding MyLinks}`. By now, you should have a listview showing the "MyAppNamespace.LinkItem" string for each item
4. Create an `ItemTemplate` for each LinkItem, where you display a Button and set its `Content` property to `{Binding Description}`
5. Create a handler for the `Click` event

I hope that's enough to send you on the right path.
Also, you should probably start by doing some of the Windows 8 tutorials to better grasp some of these concepts.

**Edit**

You didn't follow my instructions correctly..
Try this: Add a **property** to your MainPage and populate that with `LinkItem`s:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<LinkItem> LinkItems {get; set;} // <---------

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlParser pars = new HtmlParser();
        pars.Uri = "http://some website.something/";
        LinksItems = await pars.Parse();    //<-------------
    }
}
```

Make the parser return a populated collection:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<LinkItem>> Parse()
    {
        ObservableCollection<LinkItem> listDesc = new ObservableCollection<LinkItem>();
        //...
        return listDesc;
    }
```

Change the binding to `LinkItems` (the name of the collection you created above):

```
<ListView x:Name="ListLinks" ItemsSource="{Binding LinkItems}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="495" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="382">
</ListView>
```

Comment: I have edit my app but i still can't populate the ListView. When i run my app i only get black screen. I am doing somethinh wrong. Any suggestions are welcome.
I have edited the code in first post and added Xaml code to the post.

Comment: Still no luck. I have edited my code in first post. I needed to add async keyword in OnNavigatedTo method. When i go thru debuger i now get list of elements in my LinksItem = await pars.Parse(); but i still  can't see them on the ListView. I didn't add your code LinksItems = await pars.Parse(); because it was showing some errors. And thank you for your patience with me. i hope we can solve this problem. I am really getting frustrated with it.

Comment: It seems i misspelled that, I meant `LinkItems`, not `LinksItems`. This is a basic task for building a WinRT app. I strongly suggest you go through Microsoft's tutorials.

Comment: txh for help. I will do that

Comment: i finally figured it out. We forgot to put PUBLIC in front of ObservableCollection<MyApp.HtmlParser.LinkItem> LinkItems { get; set; }. And i changet the XAML and set ItemsSource="{Binding}". Final part was putting this part of code ListLinks.DataContext = LinkItems; And now i finnaly can see the ListView. You helped me alot. Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped! By the way, I believe that having `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` and `ListLinks.DataContext = LinkItems;` is equivalente to just having `ItemsSource="{Binding LinkItems}"`, but I'm not 100% sure. In the second case, the data context is implicit (because the property you're binding to is in the same class as the ListView), whereas in the first case you're explicitly setting the data context.